# C#, Cannot implicitly convert type `long' to `uint'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Whats wrong with this? I get the error on the top two lines.

```
bounds.xMin = (Mathf.FloorToInt (x / GridSize) * GridSize);
bounds.yMin = (Mathf.FloorToInt (y / GridSize) * GridSize);
bounds.xMax = bounds.xMin + GridSize;
bounds.yMax = bounds.yMin + GridSize;
```

`bounds.xMin`, `bounds.yMin`, `x`, `y` and `GridSize` are all type `uint`.

Comment: Tried casting to uint? i.e. bounds.xMin = (uint)(Mathf.FloorToInt (x / GridSize) * GridSize);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your variables are `uint`, but the return type of [`Mathf.FloorToInt`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.FloorToInt.html) is `int`.

To multiply an `uint` by an `int`, C# will convert both operands to `long`, as it's the only integer type that can represent all their possible values. The result of this operation will also be `long`.

You will need to cast the whole result or at least the result of `Mathf.FloorToInt` to `uint`.

From C# language spec:

> For the binary +, –, *, /, %, &, ^, |, ==, !=, >, <, >=, and <= operators, the operands are converted to type T, where T is the first of int, uint, long, and ulong that can fully represent all possible values of both operands. The operation is then performed using the precision of type T, and the type of the result is T